# Showing all features by real-time API with Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, html, jquery

I want to show all URL parameters or features onto a map. I have made the variable with ajax query as well as inside the loop data is printing with variable but I want to show this data with map into leaflet.

Can you suggest how to write code after calling web api?

Here I am pasting my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Example</title>
    <!--This is the experimental code for adding feature from basic authorized api to leaflet map but it is not workable code-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet.path.drag/src/Path.Drag.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    html,
    body {
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
    }

    .left {
        width: 30%;
        height: 600px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2d8659;
    }

    .right {
        width: 70%;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .tb {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column right" id='map'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* var Latitude = new Array ();
         var LocationName = new Array ();
         var Location_TblRefID = new Array ();
         var Longitude = new Array ();
         var SensorData_Value = new Array ();
         var maxdate = new Array ();
         var rno = new Array ();
         var i = new Array ();*/

        function json() {
            var username = "1111";
            var password = "111111";
            document.write("Enter1");
            document.write("\n");
            document.write("<br>");

            var url = 'http://localhost:8101/api/wms/getgiswaterlevelmonitoring';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
               
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
                },
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'json',

                success: function (datasuccess) {
                    console.log("datasuccess");
                   
                    if (datasuccess != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < datasuccess.length; i++) {
                          
                            var Latitude = datasuccess[i].Latitude;
                            var LocationName = datasuccess[i].LocationName;
                            var Location_TblRefID = datasuccess[i].Location_TblRefID;
                            var Longitude = datasuccess[i].Longitude;
                            var SensorData_Value = datasuccess[i].SensorData_Value;
                            var maxdate = datasuccess[i].maxdate;
                            var rno = datasuccess[i].rno;
                            
                        }
                        console.log("index" + i, Latitude, LocationName, Location_TblRefID, Longitude, SensorData_Value, maxdate, rno);
                        
                        //return datasuccess[i].Location_TblRefID;
                    }
                },
            });
        }
        
        var map = L.map('map').setView([22.306842, 73.181152], 4);

        var osm = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        var point = L.icon({
            iconUrl: "image/download1.png",
            iconSize: [32, 37],
            iconAnchor: [16, 37],
            popupAnchor: [0, -28],
            labelAnchor: [6, 0]
        });
        var featureStyle = {
            "color": "#ff7800",
            "weight": 5,
            "opacity": 0.2
        };

        L.geoJson(json()).addTo(map);        

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Data with console:

```
datasuccess
index85 22.300206 ParshuramBhattha 75 73.180398 5.38 2018-10-29T15:20:29 1
```

As I am printing test it is showing on console.

```
e {options: {…}, _layers: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 59, _mapToAdd: e, …}
options: {}
_initHooksCalled: true
_layers: {}
_leaflet_id: 59
_map: e {options: {…}, _container: div#map.column.right.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch.leaflet-fade-anim.leaflet-grab.leaflet-touch-dr…, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, _fadeAnimated: true, …}
_mapToAdd: e {options: {…}, _container: div#map.column.right.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch.leaflet-fade-anim.leaflet-grab.leaflet-touch-dr…, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, _fadeAnimated: true, …}
_zoomAnimated: true
__proto__: e
```

​

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include the exact error as ASCII text. This is critical for both legibility on all devices and to make the error message searchable for others.

Comment: I dont know how to take error as a ASCII text and i am very new to this visual studio and coding so if you can check this code and suggest something like this that will be helpfull

Comment: Vince just says that you should copy-paste the error message.

Comment: I have done few changes and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `L.geoJson(json()).addTo(map);` is not returning geoJson. Change this to a blank variable instead- e.g. `var test=L.geoJson();` then within your ajax success function add: `test.addData(datasuccess); map.addLayer(test);`

Comment: Thanks Will Allen, I have update it is giving some empty data while printing but with map nothing is showing any more clarification for using web api into leaflet.

Comment: Right - i don't have much to go on. Are you sure your API is returning GeoJson? If not - you could add an [L.Marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#marker) from the Latitude and Longitude in your _for_ loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your json() function does not return anything. You can just call it. Replace the line `L.geoJson(json()).addTo(map);` with `json();`.

Do you want your data to show as point markers?

Then add `L.marker(datasuccess[i].latitude,datasuccess[i].longitude]).addTo(map);` inside your AJAX success function.